# A link will work from root but from a sub folder won't

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am writing web application and I have stumbled upon a really strange issue (Most likely I am missing something very trivial). Issue:
Suppose I have a menu with 2 buttons(links) Users, Companies

The home.aspx is at root level. Here is the directory structure.

```
Home.aspx
/users/userdetail.aspx
/company/companyedit.aspx
```

When user is at Home.aspx and clicks on menu item users, he is routed to users/userdetail.aspx correctly.
However once user is on userdetail.aspx and I bring my mouse over the Companies button(link) on menu and look at the task bar of the browser and what is strange is the url that it shows is something like this

```
/users/company/companyedit.aspx
```

Which means now when I click, this page will never be found as it is being looked at in a wrong folder..
The above problem happens when link is in following format

```
users/company/companyedit.aspx
```

but if I use

```
/users/company/companyedit.aspx
```

Then the users session key is changed and which destroys the existing session.

Can some one elaborate what could be that I am overlooking (I am pretty certain I am doing something majorly dumb but can not put my finger on it)....Why it looses the application context.
Edit:
Sorry for a messy comment below, here is the sample of code that I am using to create menu items

```
<li style="background-image:url('bg.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:3px;">
   <a href="~/users/userdetails.aspx" class="arrow">Users Detail</a></li>
 </li>
 <li style="background-image:url('bg.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;  background-position:3px;">
   <a href='~/company/companyedit.aspx' class="arrow">Compnay Profile</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Try ~/company/companyedit.aspx?

Comment: I tried this but when I do this the link becomes the following

/(S(3iuuqj45sxiqwnfd2spxbyz0))/~/users/userdetails.aspx

Which means no no page is found at all

Comment: How are you creating the menu?

Comment: I have posted the code in the original question. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, will make sure to remember this tip..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Plain HTML doesn't understand the `~/` application root relative syntax. The easiest solution is to switch to using HyperLink controls. Web Forms will automatically process it and make a URL relative to the current application root.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/company/companyedit.aspx" Text="Company Profile" CssClass="arrow" />
```

By the way, you should not use inline `style` attributes. Instead, move that style information into CSS files, and apply it using a `class` attribute. It's easier to reuse the style, which reduces bandwidth. Clients can also cache the CSS file, so their pages will load quicker (and use less bandwidth!)

Answer (score 0):

While trying things I come across this

```
<%=Response.ApplyAppPathModifier('/folder/myurl.aspx') %>
```

This seems to have worked and have solved my issues. Thanks all who took time to look into it particularly  Donnelle..Thanks

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.applyapppathmodifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that method? Sounds like you shouldn't be using that. If you want to use inline code, `<%= ResolveUrl("~/folder/myurl.aspx") %>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks mason, I tried ResolveUrl but it seems like it removes the session information as well. I think problem may be in my not being well versed in ASP.net. The reason I am using sessions is that Cookies have to be disabled for safety (Qualys Scan Tool always fails a scan when cookies are enabled for example). Therefore I am using this route. Please suggest something which I should do if my approach is one which may lead to issues. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, your approach is one that might lead to issues. You should never ever use cookieless sessions. What's the issue it might lead to? People will be able to hack into other people's accounts. If Qualys Scan Tool doesn't like cookies, tell it to get over it, because they make your application more secure. Another issue is that the URL's look horrible: URL's should be user friendly. And lastly, having the session ID in the URL is bad for SEO.